# Nuget package restore - Passing in parameters to MsBuild c# API

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am looking to write a wrapper for the MSBuild C# api. I have the build all working fine, but for some odd reason I'm struggling to get Nuget package restore to run even when I pass in the parameters.

I am running this in a service that runs as **NETWORK SERVICE**

`The command ""..\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\BuildTemp\application1\packages.config" -source "" -RequireConsent -o "..\packages"" exited with code 1.`

Am I passing them in correctly?

```cs
var pc = new ProjectCollection();
var buildProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Configuration", "Release"},
    {"Platform", "Any CPU"},
    {"OutputPath", _outputPath},
    {"EnableNuGetPackageRestore", "true"}
};

var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(pc);
var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData("C:\myapplication.csproj",
                                        buildProperties,
                                        null,
                                        new[] { "Clean", "Rebuild" },
                                        null);
```

**UPDATE: this appears to work in some environments and not others. Why would this be?**

Comment: Is there an error message in the MSBuild output from nuget.exe in addition to that error code?

Comment: Nope - the only mention of it is the exception log entry mentioned. I've added that i'm running as network service.

Comment: What version of nuget.exe are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tested out this command on my local machine:

```
.\.nuget\NuGet.exe install Akavache\packages.config -source "" -RequireConsent -o packages
```

and I get an error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

which I believe is related to this bit:

`-source ""`

As I can drop that value and have it run again without an error.

Which begs the question, where are the package sources defined?

Inside the [NuGet.targets file](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e8ee017cbf50#src/Build/NuGet.targets) there's a section like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
    <!-- Package sources used to restore packages. By default, registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config will be used -->
    <!-- The official NuGet package source (https://nuget.org/api/v2/) will be excluded if package sources are specified and it does not appear in the list -->
    <!--
        <PackageSource Include="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <PackageSource Include="https://my-nuget-source/nuget/" />
    -->
</ItemGroup>
```

So I propose that when you say it works "in some environments and not others" that you don't have a config file at `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` for the service account.

Can you try changing this section in your `Nuget.targets` file in source control to be:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
    <PackageSource Include="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And see if that resolves your issues in the other environments?

Comment: This is correct - adding a Nuget.config to %APPDATA%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config solved the problem.